# XF how to lock focus on entry in iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, focus

I have some entries in my app which contain some numbers and I have a button that when I click on the button it adds one unit to the number in the entry that is focused, but the problem is that when i click the button, the entry loses the focus and keyboard disappears, although I want the entry to be focused, I found a solution for Android, but couldn't find anything for iOS!!

Does anybody know what to do? I don't want the entry to lose focus

**Update:**

```
        private void StepUpButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double value;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            if (GetEntries(i).IsFocused)
            {                   
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(GetEntries(i).Text) || GetEntries(i).Text.Equals("-"))
                {
                    value = 0.00;
                }
                else
                {
                    value = Convert.ToDouble(GetEntries(i).Text);
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    if (GetEntries(i) == GetVa1ToVb1Amp(j))
                    {
                        GetVa1ToVb1Amp(j).Text = controller.StepUpClicked(0, value).ToString("F2");
                    }
                    if (GetEntries(i) == GetIa1ToIb3Amp(j))
                    {
                        GetIa1ToIb3Amp(j).Text = controller.StepUpClicked(1, value).ToString("F3");
                    }
                    if (GetEntries(i) == GetVa1ToIb3Phase(j))
                    {
                        GetVa1ToIb3Phase(j).Text = controller.StepUpClicked(2, value).ToString("F2");
                    }
                    if (GetEntries(i) == GetVa1ToIb3Freq(j))
                    {
                        GetVa1ToIb3Freq(j).Text = controller.StepUpClicked(3, value).ToString("F3");
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code. Usually you use `becomeFirstResponder()` on the field that you want to have input, and the keyboard will show. Perhaps you can end your code with that for your button action?

Comment: I added my click button code to the question

Comment: I think subscribe the `Unfocused` event then in this event set your entry `Focus()` will achieve your effect. Make sure all of your entries subscribe this event. And this causes when you click your button, your focused entry won't lose focus.

Comment: I had tried this before and hadn't worked, tried it again and it worked!! but now I have another problem, I'm not able to dismiss the keyboard!!

Comment: @ReihanehKhaksaran That's the problem of this solution. If you want to hide the keyboard. You may subscribe an event(may be add a tap gesture to the root view), when it triggers remove all events of entries, then make them all unfocused to hide the keyboard. Finally, when one of the entries focused, subscribe these events again.